# GDB, how to pause system clock also?

Tags: c++, time, gdb

I have to debug a program running animations with gdb, but when I pause, the next animation frame is the one if no pause had occured (I mean, it calculate the delata since the previous frame's tick and the next).
Is there a way to make gdb "pause" the system clock for the program (I mean for exemple, execute step by step setting manually the number of ticks for the step, or something similar) ?

Comment: No, you can't. The system clock is controlled in kernel mode. Stopping it would also prevent you from debugging as you would have halted the entire system.

Comment: On Windows, debuggers can pause time for debugged program, but it seems that you use another OS.

Comment: If you're using Unix and can modify your code, you can change whatever routine looks at the system clock to use `setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL,...)` and `getitimer()` instead, which will provide a timer that only runs when the program is executing.

Comment: @Mgetz : yep I know^^ but is there a way to run the programm in an emulated environment it's possible to control the system clock ?

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to do this.  But it doesn't matter too much, because the idea of using a realtime clock to drive animation is faulty to begin with.  For example, if you put your computer to sleep at 1 PM and wake it up at 2 PM, is it supposed to draw one hour worth of animation?  This is, by the way, a real bug that existed in Adobe Flash about ten years ago.

You may want to add an animation clock to your program.  You can update it using the system clock by default at the start of each redraw cycle, but you could then add a mechanism to use other clocks, including a "stepwise" one that just goes as fast as it can (which, if running stepwise in gdb, will be not fast at all).